# LibGDX Setting sprite to a circle shape?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to make a ball image bind to a circle shape in LibGDX.

Currently I have this code for in the render method

```
    spriteBatch.begin();
    backWorld.getBodies(backBodies);
    for(Body body : backBodies){
        if(body.getUserData() instanceof Sprite){
            Sprite sprite = (Sprite) body.getUserData();
            sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y);
            sprite.setSize(1000, 1200);
            sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }

    world.getBodies(tmpBodies);
    for(Body bodyBall : tmpBodies){
        if(bodyBall.getUserData() instanceof Sprite){
            Sprite ballsprite = (Sprite) bodyBall.getUserData();
            ballsprite.setPosition(bodyBall.getPosition().x, bodyBall.getPosition().y);
            ballsprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        }
    }
    spriteBatch.end();
```

The first loop is getting an image and setting it to a world in the background and that works fine the image is shown. But when I included the second loop which should do the same, which is looping through the body and getting the sprites then applying it to the body it gives a nullpointerexeption.

Using this code to send the sprites to the bodies.

```
ball.setUserData(ballSprite);
back.setUserData(backgroundSprite);
```

Comment: Which line are you getting nullpointerexeption?

Comment: Im getting the exception in the second loop in the render method.

Comment: Basically I think it cannot find the ball sprite which it should be there seeing as im doing exactly the same for the background and that is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you exceeded your SpriteBatch max size?

Comment: Could be I will try making a separate sprite batch just for the ball then